Shunt resistance in an ammeter
An ammeter is formed by connecting a shunt resistance parallel to a galvanometer.
And I also learned that shunt resistance is very small as compared to the internal resistance of the galvanometer but this would mean that a very large amount of current is going to flow through the shunt resistance even for a small voltage.
My question now is: How can shunt resistance even withstand such large amount of current? Shouldn't there be large amounts of heat produced?

The shunt will have a low resistance and be designed to dissipate the heat which is generated due to the passage of a large current.
However, the power dissipated might not be as large as you might expect due to the low resistance of the shunt and hence the relatively small voltage drop acress it.
Here are three examples.
$\bf 100\,\rm A$ shunt

Voltage across shunt when a current of $100\,\rm A$ flows though it is $65\,\rm mV$.
Power dissipation is $100 \times 65\times 10^{-3}= 6.5\,\rm W$
$\bf 1000\,\rm A$ shunt

Voltage across shunt when a current of $1000\,\rm A$ flows though it is $75\,\rm mV$.
Power dissipation is $1000 \times 75\times 10^{-3}= 75\,\rm W$
$\bf 2500\,\rm A$ shunt

Voltage across shunt when a current of $2500\,\rm A$ flows though it is $100\,\rm mV$.
Power dissipation is $2500 \times 100\times 10^{-3}= 250\,\rm W$

The ammeter is connected across a break in the circuit, so the current in it is the same as in the entire circuit as a whole and is determined by total resistance of whole circuit.
The heat dissipation of a conductor is determined by the formula $Q=U \cdot I \cdot t=I^2 \cdot R \cdot t$. Exactly because the shunt has very small $R$ its dissipated energy is low.
Also, the shunt is usually designed as a radiator, so it can cool itself effectively. However, if you connect the ammeter directly to a voltage source, it will burn out instantly.
